# Convert datetime object array to date object array

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, object

I have a method which returns an `Object` array. In the `Object` array the data is datetime. I need to convert the `DateTime` array to date array. The `responseRows` returns `DateTime` data. Is there a way where I can convert `DateTime` to a date array.

Code

```
public static object[] ExtractColumn(ResponseRow[] responseRows, int columnIndex)
{
    if (columnIndex < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }            
    return responseRows.Select(x => x.RowData[columnIndex]).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: in c# there is not data type for date. Date is represented by `DateTime` with zeros as time

Comment: @wudzik ok but atleast can i convert all timestamp to zeroes

Comment: Why do you return `object[]` at all if you are returning a `DateTime[]`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter he is not converting that to DateTime so that probably got compile time error.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter my response can sometimes be numeric or string too, here i will check if my response is datetime and then will apply the conversion.

Comment: you cant directly assign other arrays to object array. you have to cast element by element into that. . `responseRows.Select(...).Cast<object>().ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date part in DateTime object with zeros for time, as there is no Date data type for c#. You can convert the column to DateTime [Convert.ToDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) object then use [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) property yo get only Date part.

```
public static DateTime[] ExtractColumn(ResponseRow[] responseRows, int columnIndex)
{
    if (columnIndex < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }            
    return responseRows.Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.RowData[columnIndex]).Date).ToArray();
}
```

**Edit** if you column is already of type DateTime then you do not need `Convert.ToDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

So you don't know if the column passed to this method is a `DateTime` column. But if it is you want to remove the time portion. Check the type and if it's `DateTime` use [`DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static object[] ExtractColumn(ResponseRow[] responseRows, int columnIndex)
{
    if (columnIndex < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    object[] objects = new object[responseRows.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {
        object data = responseRows[i].RowData[columnIndex];
        if(data is DateTime)
            data = ((DateTime)data).Date;
        objects[i] = data;
    }
    return objects;
}
```

This loop will be more efficient than your LINQ approach. If you want to see it anyway:

```
object[] objects = responseRows
    .Select(rr => rr.RowData[columnIndex])
    .Select(data => data is DateTime ? ((DateTime)data).Date : data)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your time. With the help of your comments I was able to solve my issue as shown below:

```
public static object[] ExtractColumn(ResponseRow[] responseRows, int columnIndex)
{
    if (columnIndex < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (responseRows.Any(x => x.RowData[columnIndex] is DateTime))
    {
        return responseRows.Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.RowData[columnIndex]).Date).Cast<object>().ToArray();                
    }
    return responseRows.Select(x => x.RowData[columnIndex]).ToArray();
}
```